# Proof that primary submodules of $R$ are primary ideals of $R$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I want to prove this:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. If $Q$ is a primary submodule of $R$ (as an $R$-module), then $Q$ is a primary ideal.

$Q$ is a primary submodule of $R$ if $r \in R$, $a \notin Q$ and $ra \in Q$, implies that $r^{n}R \subset Q$ for some positive integer $n$. But I can't relate this definition to that of primary ideals.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE, it is recommended on this website to share your own attempts first, this encourages others to help you !

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,r\in R$ such that $a\notin Q$ and  $ar\in Q$.

By hypothesis $r^nR\subseteq Q$.

Since $R$ has identity $r^n\in Q$.

We have just verified the definition of a primary ideal.